# Pagination adding repeating index.php and template group segments to URL

Tags: pagination, supersearch

I am helping someone with their Expression Engine site and I have an issue with pagination in some search results.

The pagination links are adding "index.php/templategroup/template" to the URL for each page. After the 3rd page click (where the pagination is regenerated) I run into the "Error: The URL contains too many segments." error because the URL has expanded.

For example, after the 3rd page click, i get **index.php/directory/results** repeating:

**hxxp://site/index.php/directory/results/index.php/directory/results/search&keywords=xyz**

I am familiar with codeigniter but this is my first attempt at working with expression engine.

Has anyone seen this before?

The site is running EE v. 240 and I believe they are using something called "Super_Search" because the template reads "exp:super_search:results"

**Edit as requested:**

SuperSearch version = 1.4.4

```
{exp:super_search:results channel="directory" paginate="both" limit="10" orderby="title" sort="desc" redirect_post="yes" status="approved"}
...content...
{paginate}
<p>Page {current_page} of {total_pages} pages {pagination_links}</p>
<br />
{/paginate}

{if super_search_no_results}
<p>No results match your search. Try again by selecting fewer or different criteria.
</p>
{/if}

{/exp:super_search:results}
```

Comment: Can you supply you template code for the pagination element and super_search tag. Also check your general configuration supplying your site index page and URL site directory. Expect it's related to a pathing issue. Also what version of Super Search?

Comment: Edited to include requested content. I'm checking index page and URL

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so I resolved this using paginate_base="templategroup/template" (paginate_base="directory/results")